# Use of TCP in ATEasy

Tags: sockets, tcp, labwindows, cvi, ateasy

I want to create a server-side program using `ATEasy` so that the `ATEasy` tests will send tests information to `LABWINDOWS\CVI` which will implement the client side.

My question is, does someone have a good tutorial or example on how to use TCP sockets in `ATEasy` as a server?

The `Winsock` example from the `ATEasy` examples isn't good enough and it is hard to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never Mind, i found this in the ATEASY documentation.

[image]

for example:

```
    ! create the socket in TCP mode
    asASocket = WsCreate(aWsTcpIp)

    ! Attach the socket
    WsBind(asASocket,"12345" ,"127.0.0.1")

    ! Set the Socket to listen for an incoming connection from a client:
    WsListen(asASocket)

    ! Attempts to return a readwrite socket to the remote client in twenty seconds. 
    ! In this stage the client should be calling WsConnect()...
    newSocket=WsAccept(asASocket,20000) 

    ! Notice that we send ( and receive ) data with the new socket that was returned by WsAccept
    WsSend(newSocket,300, ,"HELLO, HOW ARE YOU?")

    ! Attempt to Receive data from the client
    ! the client should send a message using WsSend()...
    while True
    if WsReceive(newSocket, 1000, , sMessage)>0
        exitloop
    endif 
    endwhile

    ! print the message from the client
    print sMessage

    ! close the connection
    WsClose(newSocket)
    WsClose(asASocket)
```

Each of the above functions has a return value and should be checked.

Comment: Is it possible to copy and paste the text part of that image? It'll make it easier for others to see your answer, and it'll mean that people can search for, say, `WsAccept` and find your question and answer. Thank you.